# 15 apples and 10 pears

Tags: combinatorics

There are 15 diff apples and 10 diff pears. How many ways are there for Jack to pick an apple or a ear and then for Jill to pick an apple and a pear?

The book says it's 15 * 10 * (14 + 9).

Why is one subtracted from 'both' 15 and 10 of apples and pears?

Doesn't Jack only pick 'one' of either apple or pear, not both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases: Jack picks an apple, and Jack picks a pear.

1. Jack picks an apple: Jack can make his choice in $15$ ways, and Jill then has $14\cdot10$ ways to choose one of $14$ remaining apples and one of the $10$ pears. This accounts for a total of $15\cdot14\cdot10$ possible outcomes.
2. Jack picks a pear: Jack can make his choice in $10$ ways, and Jill then has $15\cdot9$ ways to choose one of the $15$ apples and one of the $9$ remaining pears. This accounts for a total of $10\cdot15\cdot9$ possible outcomes.

The grand total is therefore

$$15\cdot14\cdot10+10\cdot15\cdot9=15\cdot10(14+9)\;,$$

just as the book says.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  After Jill picked an apple and a pear, there're 14 apples left and 9 pears left, therefore ...